# Magento - Sort PDF Invoice products by location

Tags: php, magento, pdf, stock, invoice

Im working on a solution for Magento 1 for the PDF Invoices. We want the invoices to show products sorted by stock_location. All of our locations starts with a letter lige A,B,C etc. And after that some numbers.

I want the invoices to show the products by the alphabet so when we find the products we start from A to Z, so you know from top to bottom. I just cant figure out how to solve this?

```
foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
    if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
        continue;
    }
    /* Draw item */
    $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
    $page = end($pdf->pages);
}
```

Anyone else ever wanted this and maybe got a clue which way i should go? :)

- Thanks for your time.

Comment: maybe put all locations in the array and sort it alphabetically

Comment: Not sure i got the posibility for that. The data isnt handled in the same file as the data is sent. Is it possible to call some function in magento i dont know of? Added code to post

Comment: Nobody else wanted this? It just make it much easier to collect all the products for the orders. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how can do that in Magento but i am sharing some idea that how can you do that in PHP try like this .hope it will help for you

```
$response[] = array(
                        'product_id' => $stock->product_id,
                        'product_name' => $stock->product_name,
                        'stock_id' => $stock->stock_id,
                        'stock_location' => $stock->stock_location,

                        );
                    }

                foreach ($response as $rec) {
                    $stock_location[] = $rec['stock_location'];
                    $title[] = strtolower($rec['product_name']);
                }
                //print_r($stock_location);

                array_multisort($stock_location, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $title, SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING, $response);

                print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
$items = $invoice->getAllItems();
        $sortedItems = array();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            $sortedItems[$prod->getStockLocation()] = $item;
        }

        ksort($sortedItems);

        foreach ($sortedItems as $item){
            if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Draw item */
            $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
            $page = end($pdf->pages);
        }
```